# Zoom on the features on map from the drop down list

Tags: leaflet, zoom, dropdownlist

How can I add a drop down list on HTML so that when I select a item in list, zoom on a feature on the map in HTML page occured. I will use Leaflet map for that purpose. I want to select provinces from drop down list and map go over there.

As well I can't load my GeoJSON file from drive to the map, but that wasn't displayed and Google map is disappeared as well when I add the GeoJSON code part.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Leaflet - Sample</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./leaflet.css"/>
        <script src="./leaflet.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css"/>
        <script src="./leaflet.ajax.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="mapContainer"></div>
        <form action="/action_page.php">
            <label for="İl">İl:</label>
            <select name="İl" id="İl">
              <option value="İstanbul">İstanbul</option>
              <option value="Ankara">Ankara</option>
              <option value="İzmir">İzmir</option>
              <option value="Antalya">Antalya</option>
            </select>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
          </form>
    </body>
    
    <script>
        var map = L.map('mapContainer', {
            center: [40.97137457539843, 29.098965299739625],
            zoom: 13
        });
        //var Provinces= "Provinces GeoJSON.geojson";  
    
        var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("Provinces GeoJSON.geojson");       
        geojsonLayer.addTo(map);
        //L.geoJSON('Provinces GeoJSON.geojson').addTo(map);

        var OSM = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', 
            {
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            }
        ).addTo(map);
        
        
    </script>
</html>
```

the GeoJSON file is as follow which generated by https://geojson.io/#map=5.26/39.146/35.244 from my shapefile

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ILLER": "ADANA"
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "MultiPolygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              [
                35.608799999935684,
                36.65432999972768
              ],
              [
                35.609259999556286,
                36.65251999992984
              ],
              [
                35.60953999987288,
                36.65274999974014
              ],
              [
               .
               .
               .

 [
                31.305530000056855,
                41.10922000013863
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The resulted HTML on browser is as here.
The features not displayed. There isn't any error displayed.

[image]
Any suggestion or code example?

Comment: Also, any errors in the browser debugger console?

Comment: What about browser debugger network section? Any errors there when you load GeoJSON data?