# Zoom on selected features from drop down list in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, zoom, dropdownlist

I want to add a GeoJSON layer to leaflet map from local

a drop down list in above the map

and when I select features the map will zoomed on

the dataset is call on head part as

```
<script src="./Provinces-GeoJSON.js"></script>
```

here is the required code parts

the part in body tag

```
        <label for="OSB">OSB:</label>
        <select name="OSB" id="osb">
            <option value="Mersin Silifke">Mersin Silifke</option>
            <option value="Denizli Makine İhtisas">Denizli Makine İhtisas</option>
            <option value="Kocaeli Gebze Güzeller">Kocaeli Gebze Güzeller</option>
        </select>
        <input id="git" type="button" value="Git">
```

and the  part in script part

```
   let osbLayer = {};

                
L.geoJSON(jsonİlOSBBase, {
    onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
        console.log(feature,layer);
        osbLayer[feature.properties.İL_OSBName]=layer;
    }
}).addTo(map)

document.getElementById('git').addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    let osb = document.getElementById('osb');
    map.fitBounds(osbLayer[osb].getBounds());
})
```

but it doesn't work.

here is part of my .js file

```
let jsonİlOSBBase ={
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "İl_OSB_--",
"crs": { "type": "name", "properties": { "name": "urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84" } },
"features": [
{ "type": "Feature", "properties": { "İL_OSBName": "Bursa MustafaKemalPaşa Mermerciler" }, "geometry": { "type": "MultiPolygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ [ 28.559284046892159, 39.905347869297572 ], [ 28.558677949705665, 39.905545299803769 ], ....] ] ] ] } }
]
}
```

Have any suggestions for that?

Comment: What happened to your previous question https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/460574/zoom-on-the-features-on-map-from-the-drop-down-list? Did you see the last question in the comments? Don't expect answers if you don't react to comments.

Comment: dear TomazicM
i see the comments of course and edit the question to involve the required info based on the provided comments.. (as i mensioned There isn't any error displayed.) but any answer was not posted yet ... so i add my last findings and repost by more detail to get better answered

Comment: i add the first part of my .js file as well

Comment: unfortunatley i cant get my required answer in that post dear IvanSanchez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible way to solve this is to iterate through GeoJSON features, use `.getLayerId` function to get individual feature ids and construct HTML drop down selection options, setting feature id as selection value. When selected, this value can then be used to get desired feature with `.getLayer` function.

Relevant part of the code could then look something like this (select feature background color is set to green):

```
var OSBBaseLayer = L.geoJSON(jsonİlOSBBase).addTo(map);

var selectOptions = '';
OSBBaseLayer.eachLayer(function(layer) {
  var layerId = OSBBaseLayer.getLayerId(layer);
  selectOptions += '<option value="' + layerId + '">' + layer.feature.properties['İL_OSBName'] + '</option>';
});
document.getElementById('osb').innerHTML = selectOptions;

var selectedFeature;

document.getElementById('git').addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  var selectedFeatureId = document.getElementById('osb').value;
  if (selectedFeature) {
    if (statesLayer.getLayerId(selectedFeature) == selectedFeatureId) return;
    statesLayer.resetStyle(selectedFeature);
  }
  
  selectedFeature = statesLayer.getLayer(selectedFeatureId);
  map.fitBounds(selectedFeature.getBounds());
  selectedFeature.setStyle({fillColor: 'green'});
});
```